# New header displays correctly on index and product pages, but not category pages

Tags: magento-1.7

I have just gone live with a new header design on my Magento store. It is working correctly on the index page, and is also working correctly on my product pages.

However, although showing 99% correctly on my category pages, there is one big error on that type of page.

I have designed a `20px high`, `100% width` (my store is `960px` fixed), solid colour bar at the very top of the page behind some of the account links (sign in, my account, etc).

This shows correctly on the index and product pages, but is missing on the category pages.

The CSS I've used for the div is as follows:

```
{ background:#F389AF;width:100%;height:20px;position:absolute;z-index:-100; }
```

I'm a bit unsure why this isn't displaying, any ideas?! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: make sure that your css file include on catlog category listing page.

Comment: FIXED - to get the full width bar I put the div in 1column.phtml, which is why it worked on my index and product pages. However my category pages use 2columns-left.phtml and I didn't include the div there. Stupid of me to miss that until now :)

Comment: hmm (y) it's happen buddy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your one column and 2 column files in tamplate/page folder.

also check the css file include or not.